# How to display a 2D array in jTable?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have a static 2D array called `Status.Data[][]` and a Column header called `Status.Columns[]`.

I am using net beans and I want to be able to have the arrays populate the table.

```
    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        jTable1.setColumnModel(new DefaultColumnModel(Status.Data, Status.Columns));
    }
```

This throws an error that it is expecting a TableColumnModel.

```
    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        jTable1.setColumnModel(new TableColumnModel(Status.Data, Status.Columns));
    }
```

This says java.swing.table.TableColumnModel is abstract and cannot be instantiated.

I would even be happy if I could figure out how to make it display when the window is opened.

How do I populate my table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create the table model and then pass it to the table constructor:

```
TableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(Status.Data, Status.Columns);
JTable table = new JTable(model);
```

Answer (score 2):

use javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel

```
DefaultTableModel(Object[][] data, Object[] columnNames)
```